# Creating dataframe with all the author connections

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

I have a dataframe of authors

```
  id|author_1|author_2|author_3|author_4|author_5
   1|Joe M   |Sally K |Terry O 
   2|Jack T  |Mike  K
```

I want to create a data frame with all the possible connections between the authors. The dataframe should look like this:

```
  id|source  |target  |
   1|Joe M   |Sally K | 
   1|Joe M   |Terry O | 
   1|Sally K |Terry O |
   2|Jack T  |Mike  K |
```

The goal is to have all the unique connections between the authors. For a given ID there can be up to 5 authors and I want the list for all the possible connections for all the authors. I also want to avoid duplicates because A - B == B - A.

I am not sure how to start.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Idea is create all combinations with length 2 by all columns without `id` and pass to `DataFrame` constructor:

```
from  itertools import combinations

L = [(k,) + x for k, v in df.set_index('id').T.items() for x in combinations(v.dropna(), 2)]

df = pd.DataFrame(L, columns=['id','source','target'])
print (df)
   id   source   target
0   1    Joe M  Sally K
1   1    Joe M  Terry O
2   1  Sally K  Terry O
3   2   Jack T   Mike K
```

Comment: Thank you! What if I did not want to drop the duplicates? Would I use L = [(k,) + x for k, v in df.set_index('id').T.items() for x in combinations(v, 2)]

Comment: @Py.rookie89 - Do you think `from  itertools import combinations_with_replacement

L = [(k,) + x for k, v in df.set_index('id').T.items() for x in combinations_with_replacement(v.dropna(), 2)]` ?